# Not able to find 8172 port for WebDeploy

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, webdeploy

on Windows 2012 R2 server I'm not able to use 8172 port for WebDeploy.
i have installed webdeploy 3.6.
Error is like **it's already in use** but when i executed the 
**netstat -aon | findstr :8172** command it's not showing any result.
[image]

Comment: Very likely that it has been reserved, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#reserved-urls

Comment: You could try command netsh http show urlacl to find the conflict reserved URL. If you could find the conflict URLacl. Then rul netsh http delete urlacl. When you get back to windows management service you may see WMSVCcan't start. Then change ip address to unassigned-> start, then you should see it being re-registered. Now you could try to change the ip address back to 10.xxx.xxx.xxx